# Call "ThisWorkbook"

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to switch between a template (hard coded) and a dynamic report which changes name weekly (ThisWorkbook). I am struggling with calling the variable x to bring focus to the workbook. I am copying the template formulas and pasting them into the dynamic report.

```
Sub wkbk()
   Dim x As Excel.Workbook
   Set x = ThisWorkbook
   Dim pth As String
   pth = x.FullName
   Windows(pth).Activate
End Sub
```

Here is the VBA code I am using:

```
Windows("BBU_CMD_TEMPLATE.xlsx").Activate
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Windows(pth).Activate
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `x.Activate`? Also, why are you needing to activate a workbook if you want to copy data to/from it?

Comment: ThisWorkbook is the workbook running the code. If you are trying to refer to an outside workbook you will need another way of referring to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use `ThisWorkbook.Activate`? There's generally no need to assign a variable to represent a built-in like `ThisWorkbook` so the rest of those variables are unnecessary unless you're using them elsewhere in that procedure (from the snippet provided, you aren't, so you don't need them).

```
Sub wkbk()
   ThisWorkbook.Activate
End Sub
```

However, what's the point of `wkbk` procedure? If solely to activate the workbook, that's not needed either and [there are plenty of reasons to avoid `Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

```
Sub CopySheetFromTemplateToThisWorkbook()
Dim tmplt As Workbook
On Error Resume Next
Set tmplt = Workbooks("BBU_CMD_TEMPLATE.xlsx")
If tmplt Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Template file needs to be open..."
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0
With ThisWorkbook    
    tmplt.ActiveSheet.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
End With
End Sub
```